# PYTHON NO ME DEJA DIGITAR LA ENTRADA EN CONSOLA Y TAMPOCO GENERA SALIDA

Tags: python-3.x, input

El código a continuación es un ejercicio de condicionales y funciones.

Cuando le quito el `if`, me devuelve perfectamente el elemento agregado por consola. Sin embargo, al ingresar los valores a la función para que sean valoradas por el interprete, me devuelve pues el resultado de `p_base`.

El código no marca error, pero tampoco me entrega ninguna salida.

Agradecería muchísimo su ayuda.

```
p_base = ['mozzarella', 'tomate']

x = input()

def colocar_categoria(x):
    def agregar_elemento(x):
        p_base.append(x)
        return p_base

    x = agregar_elemento(x)

    if x == 'peperoni':
        print('tu pizza no es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + p_base)
    
    elif x == 'jamon':
        print('tu pizza no es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + p_base)
    
    elif x == 'salmon':
        print('tu pizza no es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + p_base)
    
    elif x == 'pimiento':
        print('tu pizza es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + p_base)
    
    elif x == 'salmon':
        print('tu pizza es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + p_base)
    else:
        print('ingrese un valor valido')



colocar_categoria(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está aqui:

```
x = agregar_elemento(x)
```

Estas reemplazando el valor ingresado por el usuario con el resultado de la función.

```
def agregar_elemento(x): 
    p_base.append(x) 
    return p_base
```

Luego de la llamada, `x` vale `p_base`.

Solución:

```
agregar_elemento(x)
```

Comment: agradezco mucho tu respuesta, si leyendo mi codigo me di cuenta que estaba cambiando los parametros que recibia la funcion, a final de cuentas quedo asi.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # tengo una pizza con elementos basicos que compatiran todas
p_base = ['mozzarella', 'tomate']

#aqui se ingreesa el ingrediente extra para la pizza solo puede ser 1 
elemento = input()

#mediante esta funcion tomamos el ingrediente deseado por el cliente para poder agregarlo  a la lista inicial
def agregar_elemento(elemento):
        p_base.append(elemento)
        return p_base

#aqui se llama a la funcion para que pueda ser tomada por sus declaraciones
agregar_elemento(elemento)

#esta funcion determina la categoria de la pizza e imprime sus valores
def colocar_categoria(elemento):
    if elemento == 'peperoni':
        print('tu pizza no es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + str(p_base))
    elif elemento == 'jamon':
        print('tu pizza no es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + str(p_base))
    elif elemento == 'salmon':
        print('tu pizza no es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + str(p_base))
    elif elemento == 'pimiento':
        print('tu pizza es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + str(p_base))
    elif elemento == 'tofu':
        print('tu pizza es vegetariana')
        print('tiene estos elementos ' + str(p_base))
    else: 
        print('ingrese un valor valido')

#aqui se llama a la funcion para que pueda ser tomada por la funcion 
colocar_categoria(elemento)
```